# Prevent windows explorer from changing path when folder is deleted

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I quite often drop and re-create folders. If an explorer window is open in a folder which gets deleted, explorer will automatically jump to the nearest existing parent folder as soon as it detects the delete.

I wonder if there is any way of making explorer stay put, so that I can just refresh the view when the folder has been re-created.

Answer (score 0):

You have not stated which version of Windows you are using, but the short answer to your question is "No, you can't turn off the auto-refresh feature of Windows Explorer."

An alternative solution is to use a third party file manager. Here is some [comparison information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers) about different ones.

Comment: I use a multitude of windows versions, if I can do it in any I would like to know!

Comment: Oh, and I don't really need to turn of auto-refresh per se, I just want to prevent the "jump to nearest parent" behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I like this question because it'll take a little outside-the-box thinking to get what you want. It is true that a local NTFS drive will act as you've described and there is little that you can do about that. Also, if you use SMB it'll still work the same way. I have discovered a way to get Explorer to work as you've described though. If you install the FTP service (it's in programs and features; the features area will have it under IIS) then you can go to a local FTP folder (using the FTP protocol) and Explorer won't be able to detect changes (thank god for protocols beyond the reach of MS). If you don't have MS FTP service due to the edition of Windows that you run then look for a free FTP server software package online and use that instead. Have fun!